# What is the difference between withContext(Dispatchers.IO) and with(Dispatchers.IO) in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am a newbie to coroutines and was trying to run some code in a different thread, and I came across two similar-sounding methods `withContext` and `with(Dispatcher)`. What is the difference between the two? I assume that they both run code passed in the code block in a different thread but I am not sure.

Please elaborate and explain

Comment: why the [java] tag?

Comment: The use of `with` is almost certainly a bug.

Answer (score 4):

`with()` is just a [scope function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/scope-functions.html#with) and is not related to coroutines. It will not affect the thread that your code runs on.

`withContext()` is a way to switch coroutine contexts, including switching to a different dispatcher. So, if your goal is "run this on a different thread", you want `withContext()`, not `with()`.